# How to scroll to a particluar index in collection view in swift

Tags: ios, iphone, arrays, swift, uicollectionview

We have a collection view. I have made a calendar which shows dates horizontally & I scroll dates horizontally. Now on screen I see only 3-4 dates. Now I want to auto scroll to a particular selected date when calendar screen I shown.So the date I want to scroll to is not visible yet.

For that I got the indexpath for particular cell. Now I am trying to scroll it to particular indexpath.

```
  func scrollCollectionView(indexpath:IndexPath)
  {
   // collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexpath, at: .left, animated: true)
    //collectionView.selectItem(at: indexpath, animated: true, scrollPosition: .left)
    collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexpath, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)
    _ = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "DayCell", for: indexpath) as? DayCell

  }
```

Please tell how can I implement it?

Comment: It seems like there is a problem with calling scrollCollectionView. Where are you calling this method from?

Comment: just after my collection view is ready

Comment: It would be helpful if you post your code where you create, prepare, and ultimately add your collection view for us to see.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

In `viewDidLoad` of your controller, you can write the code for scrolling to a particular index path of collection view.

```
self.collectionView.scrollToItem(at:IndexPath(item: indexNumber, section: sectionNumber), at: .right, animated: false)
```

Comment: how to pass my particular indexpath to (item: indexNumber, section: sectionNumber)

Comment: What do you mean by your indexPath? Isn't the above code doing the same?

Comment: "animated: false" was the key for me

Answer (score 15):

In Swift 4, this worked for me:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {

    collectionView.scrollToItem(at:IndexPath(item: 5, section: 0), at: .right, animated: false)
}
```

placing it anywhere else just resulted in weird visuals.

**Note** - an edit was made to my original post just now which wanted to change `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` to `viewDidAppear()`. I rejected the edit because placing the function's code anywhere else (including `viewDidAppear`) didn't work at the time, and the post has had 10 upvots which means it must have been working for others too. I mention it here in case anyone wants to try `viewDidAppear`, but I'm pretty sure I would have tried that and wouldn't have written "placing it anywhere else just resulted in weird visuals" otherwise. It could be an XCode update or whatever has since resolved this; too long ago for me to remember the details.

Comment: It's worked for me at viewDidLayoutSubview
but every time i am trying to swipe left or right it's let me back to the same index

Comment: Can't remember the details off hand, but Is your collection view data populated properly? And have you implemented the appropriate delegate methods?

Comment: This will be triggered every time the view controller layouts its subviews which can be multiple times, so I would advise against doing this.

Comment: I also faced the issue Muhammed mentioned when the code was written in viewDidLayoutSubviews. But when I placed the same code in viewDidAppear, it worked!!

Answer (score 8):

You can use this

```
self.collectionView.scrollToItem(at:IndexPath(item: index, section: 0), at: .right, animated: false)
```

Answer (score 6):

I used your answer @PGDev but I put it in `viewWillAppear` and it works well for me.

```
self.collectionView?.scrollToItem(at:IndexPath(item: yourIndex, section: yourSection), at: .left, animated: false)
```

Comment: what should i use in "(item: yourIndex, section: yourSection)" in order to focus a particular cell?

Answer (score 3):

tested this

```
func scrollToIndex(index:Int) {
     let rect = self.collectionView.layoutAttributesForItem(at:IndexPath(row: index, section: 0))?.frame
     self.collectionView.scrollRectToVisible(rect!, animated: true)
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

In viewDidLoad of your controller, you can write the code

```
     self.myCollectionView.performBatchUpdates(nil) { (isLoded) in

     if isLoded{
                 self.myCollectionView.scrollToItem(at: self.passedContentOffset, at: [.centeredVertically,.centeredHorizontally], animated: false)
               }
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

I have tried all, but for me, it only works with adding one extra line

```
       self.collectionView.scrollToItem(at:IndexPath(item: index, section: 0), at: .right, animated: false)
     
       collectionView.layoutSubviews()
```

you can call it anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
   super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
   yourcollectionView.scrollToItem(at:IndexPath(item: passedIndex ?? 0, section: 0), at: .centeredVertically, animated: false)
}
```