# How can I scroll a collection view cell to the middle of the visible area

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, swift3

I am using `UICollectionView` to create a single row of cells which serve as an `index` to display a table view section with more details. The user can scroll the cells and select a particular cell which brings up the corresponding detail by scrolling a `UITableview` section below. This works fine. I would like a specific cell to be roughly in the middle of the row of visible cells when the view is first shown after being `segued` from a previous screen. Is there something comparable to `scrollTableTo` in collection view? In [How to scroll to a particular index in collection view in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40786699/how-to-scroll-to-a-particluar-index-in-collection-view-in-swift) there is a reference to `scrollToItem` but I need help understanding how to use it. It compiles and executes in `viewDidAppear`. The `UITableview` is scrolled as expected. The item i in the code segment cell is the item I want displayed. However, the cells are not changed (The first item on the list is displayed on the left). What works is the same statement in the `shouldSelectAt`. The cell that was selected is centered in the visible set.

```
   override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    // DOES NOT WORK
    var i = 0
    for workorder in dm.workOrderNames {
        if (workOrderToBeDisplayed == workorder) {
            scrollTableTo(section: i, row: 0)
            print("workorder = \(workorder) i = \(i)")
            return
        }
        i = i + 1
    }

    workOrderView.scrollToItem(at:IndexPath(item: i, section: 0), at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: false)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, shouldSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
 // WORKS 
 workOrderView.scrollToItem(at:IndexPath(item: indexPath.item, section: 0), at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: false)
    return true
}
```

Comment: Is item index(i) getting updated properly ? If yes, then execute scrollToItem in dispatch async (main thread).

Comment: The view controller is on the main thread. See the edited code for the case that works.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        self.yourCollection.scrollToItem(at: IndexPath(item: collectionSize/2, section: 0), at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: false)
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add why this works to make this better for future readers. Thanks!