# Scroll to particular index UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

Ive tried the "solution" to my problem of trying to start my UICollectionView at a particular index from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40786699/how-to-scroll-to-a-particluar-index-in-collection-view-in-swift) post:

Yet upon using this "solution" I get the following issues:

[image: clipping UIcollectionView]

On top of the clipping It does not scroll to the new index. My `UICollectionView` is inside a `UItableViewCell` class, so I've placed the solution in `awakeFromNib` - didn't work either. So, I've placed it in `cellForRowAt(indexPath:)` method in the view controller which didn't as well. Any suggestions?

Comment: Hey Zack, please show us the code of your solution :)

Comment: Zack can you please add code which time you want to scroll?

Comment: click the this it has my code @VDPurohit

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved this by not using the above post but instead came up with this solution that worked for me:

```
  internal func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if !onceOnly {

        let indexToScrollTo = IndexPath(item: 12, section: 0)
        self.collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexToScrollTo, at: .left, animated: false)
        onceOnly = true
    }
}
```

Hope it helps others out :D

Comment: If you have a better one Id love to see it. Id appreciate if you don't downvote me too please. @VinGazoil