# iOS - Is there any method that will call after collection view loaded (set layout, set datasource)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview, diffabledatasource

I want to perform scroll to particular index path after collection view load complete. Is there any method that inform the collection view is loaded (set layout, set datasource)

*NOTE: Im using DiffableDatasource to display collection view. I tried .apply snapshot completion - not working for me.*

Answer (score 1):

Scroll to desired indexPath on completion of snapshot apply action working for me.
Here is the code:

```
dataSource.apply(snapshot, animatingDifferences: false) { in
     /// Scroll to indexPath action.
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Waiting for the completion of the snapshot apply action, before performing scroll actions, is indeed essential

Answer (score 0):

Please check where are you calling you collectionView.reloadData() lastly. after that line, you can simply call this.

```
self.collectionView.scrollToItem(at:IndexPath(item: indexNumber, section: sectionNumber), at: .right, animated: false)
```

For reference, visit this link.
[How to scroll to a particluar index in collection view in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40786699/how-to-scroll-to-a-particluar-index-in-collection-view-in-swift)

Answer (score 0):

In swift collectionView comes with scrollView property and that you can use to scroll to the particular item's index

```
yourCollectionView.scrollToItem(at: desiredIndexPath, at: UICollectionView.ScrollPosition, animated: false)
```

for more information please go through this [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview/1618046-scrolltoitem)

Answer (score -3):

let uid = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "id")

```
    let url = URL(string: "https://iroidtechnologies.in/MeatShop/index.php?route=api/completeapi&api_token=")!
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.setValue( "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.httpMethod = "post"
    let poststring = "user_id=\(uid!)&key=\("koFCpCMzm8hhn9ULj0BnUzZkpqM3rg9Mqdii3FwPRjBwZFQWriIJYgB5jjOhNIyasSl4RrmCFLW3tHDRtI39viQbYEP7nEkYvba2wstThYWjvkndZq0zaXJaWjuqeZo8vR3MMHa6OhBDKsFPmWOlIM4H1TgB1fudQndGKzUPg8YhAoaAoCxZ562zjbQdPO73ZkwyPV7iOIkyH11ZLAN42a5dgLH22Rs1VasEWBKdfkqMLPfDbLQpF9Ofqah4fqwc")"
    print("poststring--->>",poststring)
    request.httpBody = poststring.data(using: .utf8)
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request){(data,response,error)in
        let mydata = data
        
        do {
           print("mydata__>>",mydata)
            do{
                self.getdata.append(mydata!)
                self.jsondata = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: self.getdata as Data, options: []) as! NSArray
                print("jsondata___>>",self.jsondata)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.raw.reloadData()
                    
                }
                
        
            }
            
        }
        catch{
            print("error",error.localizedDescription)
        
    }
        
    }
    task.resume()
```

Comment: It seems you posted some code on the wrong question. This question is about scrolling a collection view after it has loaded. Also, when posting an answer (that actually applies to the question), please do not post code-only answers. A good answer explains what was wrong and it explains how the answer solves the issue.